# Why var_dump of file_get_contents($myFile) return length of my file but empty string?

Tags: php

I am stuck on a point that does not allow me to continue in my program.

This point is that my `var_dump (file_get_contents ($ myFile))` returns to me `string (337) ""`.

My file is an HTML file. Here is a screenshot of my file :

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Did you look at it in source view?

Comment: Don't post code as an image...

Comment: if you look at the dump in a browser, the HTML gets rendered and since the HTML document doesn't have visible output, it shows an empty string

Comment: It probably gets rendered

Comment: try something like htmlentities(file_getcontents('file.html'))

Comment: Thank you @Bernhard for your answer. It's just what i'm looking.